# UVA 11340-Newspaper doesn't accept answer

Tags: c++, arrays, printf, ascii, cout

I made a solution for problem 11340 in OnlineJudge.org
(https://onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=2315), problem is quite simple, read an article and determine its cost based on a list of prices per character.

I get the correct output on the given tests and also on the extra test found on https://www.udebug.com/UVa/11340, yet my code throws Wrong Answer on the judge. This is not the first time it happens to my on this page that a code that works is not being accepted from completely tangential reason (e.g code not being accepted when using cin but working with scanf)

Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>
//#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

//Idea: Store the values on a positional array where their position is determined by 
//its ASCII value, then just read the article and calculate add the costs up.
int main(){

    int t;
    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        float cost = 0.0;//Final cost
        int K; cin>>K;//How many characters with value will exist
        int char_costs[300] = {0};//We set the ASCII value of the character as the position, 
                                  //and inside how much it costs
                                  //300 just to be safe, but 128 must have been perhaps enough (amount of ascii values)

        char character;
        for(int i = 0; i < K; i++){
            cin>>character;//read the character
            cin>>char_costs[(int)character];//save the cost of that character on its ASCII value postion
        }

        int M; cin>>M;//Read how many lines of a given article to read
        string current_line;//Current line of the article
        for(int i = 0; i <= M; i++){
            getline(cin,current_line);//read the line
            for(int current_char = 0; current_char <= current_line.length(); current_char++){//Go through each character of the current line
                cost += char_costs[current_line[current_char]];//Add the cost of that character (if it wasn't given then it's zero)
            }
        }
        cost /= 100.0;//Divde the cost by 100 (since we are given costs in cents)
        printf("%.2lf$\n",cost);//print it
    }
}
```

Comment: The loop condition `current_char <= current_line.length()` will lead to you also using the null-terminator of the string.

Comment: Similarly, the loop condition `i <= M` will cause the loop to iterate `M + 1` times.

Comment: Replacing into `current_char < current_line.length()` didn't make a difference, yet weirdly enough if I run `i < M` makes the program not read the last line, perhaps something to do with the `getline()`?

Comment: Please show a [mre] (without relying on external links). What is the supposed to do? What is the input? What is the expected and actual output? Using floats for money is usually discouraged due to limited accuracy

Comment: Not sure if this is an issue in this scenario, but during the addition of all the costs `float` could result in inacurracies. Better go with `uint64_t` and print `cost/100` and `cost%100` (possibly padded) separated by a decimal separator to be sure no rounding issues occur. If you don't want to do this, at least go with `double` to decrease the likelyhood of the issue occuring.

Comment: I think I see one major problem: I assume you end al linput by using the `Enter` key? That key will be added to the input buffer as a newline (`'\n'`). So after the `cin>>M` there will be a newline in the input buffer, and it will be the first character that `getline` reads. Please take some time to think about what happens when `getline` reads a newline...

Comment: Now I see why when I would `i < M` it would not work and stop one line before. This is because it was always reading an `\n` instead of the first line. I decided to add a `cin.ignore()`  right after `cin>>M` to clear the character from the input buffer, yet it's yielding Wrong Answer. I found a solution similar to mine online in where they use `getchar()` through each character as they appear on the buffer, but I still want to understand why is my approach not being accepted.

Answer (score 1):

The range of `char` is `[-128, 127]`.
But, the input may contains Extended ASCII characters which in range `[0, 255]`.

For example, we get an input line as below:

```
© 100
```

Code point of character © is 169.

```
char character;
cin >> character; //get ©
//character = 169 (exceed 127)
//so, character is converted to -87
```

Your table is: `int char_costs[300]`.

```
char_costs[(int)character] 
= char_costs[-87], out of range of array.
```

We can declare char_costs as below to fix:

```
map<int, int> char_costs
```

Hope this helpful :)